# React-Router NavLink active color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hey guys I really don't understand why is this happening. When I start the app, everything is okay. First item in menu has active class. But when I click on another item in menu, this item also receives this class active and previous class active has not been removed.

**Picture for better understanding**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div className="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Domov</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">O nás</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/portfolio" activeClassName="active">Portfólio</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/contact" activeClassName="active">Kontakt</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    .menu ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;

        li{
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 1.5em;
            color: black;
            font-weight: 400;

            a{
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;

                &.active{
                    color:$mainColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because even though you navigated to a new link the first link `/` still evaluates as true.

You need to add `exact` to your `NavLink`s

```
<NavLink exact to="/portfolio" activeClassName="active">Portfólio</NavLink>
```

This will make sure the active class is only added if the route matches exactly as the `to` link

Comment: Thank you! I though it has to be this kind of small mistake.

Comment: Just keep in mind one more result that will happen by adding `exact` to your `NavLink`, without `exact` the router would render all matching pages (even partial matches) so your home page would have been displayed even when you navigate to any other page, however after adding `exact` it will only render what matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom v6 you could also use the `end` statement for your "/" route. In react-router-dom v6 you could also use `activeStyle={{color: yourcolor}}` as a prop of the NavLink. I wasnt able to make the solution mentioned above work on the actual v6.